# Space between div that works on mobile too

Tags: css, alignment, media

Assuming that i have something like:

```
<div class="features small">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <div class="feature-items">
            <div class="feature">
                <img style="" src="icon1.png" />
                <div class="title">
                    <h4>Title 1</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <img style="" src="icon2.png" />
                <div class="title">
                    <h4>Title 2</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <img style="" src="icon3.png" />
                <div class="title">
                    <h4>Title 3</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature">
                <img style="" src="icon4.png" />
                <div class="title">
                    <h4>Title 4</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i set some space between every single "feature" div that works on mobile too? Now'm i'm trying this in CSS:

`.feature { padding-right: 4rem; }`

But for mobile i have to use media queries. And if i don't want to use media?

Comment: Do u want apply space for mobile screen without using media query css ?

Comment: yeah, what i need is to apply a space between. With padding-right it works (on desktop) but then obviusly i have to set media queries for mobile. But if i don't want to use media queries?

Comment: You can call css file for specified screen. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobiel-device.css" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest only applying the padding at desktop breakpoints, and not setting styles at for desktop and then overriding for mobile. This is an anti-pattern within the cascade.

So I'd just do:

```
@media screen (min-width: 64em) {
    .feature { padding-right: 4rem; } 
}
```

There isn't a way I know of without using media queries at all unless you are changing styles with js - which seems like overkill for what you are trying to do. I wrote a little bit about mobile-first css patterns in this short post:

http://mrmrs.io/writing/2014/08/18/mobile-first-css/